# Python pivot table groupby or transpose/unstack

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, pivot-table

Hi so I have a dataframe on IT ticket incoming time that looks like this

```
   Feedback time          time               hour       Shift   
0   12/2/20 23:58   2020-12-02 23:58:00      23     Shift 3 
1   12/2/20 10:20   2020-12-02 10:20:00      10     Shift 1 
2   12/2/20 11:40   2020-12-02 11:40:00      11     Shift 1 
....
458 11/18/20 16:01  2020-11-18 16:01:00      16     Shift 2
```

Here the earliest date is 11/18/2020 and latest is 12/2/2020

And "Shift" is defined as

```
conditions = [(df['hour'] >= 7) & (df['hour'] < 15),
    (df['hour'] >= 15) & (df['hour'] < 23),
    (df['hour'] < 7) | (df['hour'] >= 23)]
```

Expected output

```
               11/18-11/25   11/26-12/2
Shift   Hour     
Shift 1  7       xx
         8      
         9      
        ...
         15       
Shift 2  16      
         17       
         ...
         22     
Shift 3  23     
         0      
         1       
         ...
         6
```

Basically column will be groupby week, index will be Shift and then hour during the day.
For xx, I want to count the frequency of "hour" during 7am interval, sum for the whole week, and then get the average value for that whole week (11/18-11/25 in this case), also need it to populate all the empty cells.

I have tried this

```
s = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Shift',"Hour"],columns =['Time'] ,values = ['hour'],aggfunc=[len])
```

but my first row is only showing every day, not aggregated by week

Thank you so much!